# Get property value from object tree in a recursive way

Tags: javascript, recursion

Consider the following structure,

```
let condition = { and: [ { id: 3 }, { pageId: '1' } ] }
```

I want to get the `id` property value in a recursive way, it can be also nested inside other conditions.

for example the structure could be like that

```
let condition = {or: [{ and: [ { id: 3 }, { pageId: '1' } ] }, {age: 10}]}
```

I ended using this but I don't like the final syntax

```
  function getIdConditionValue(cond) {
    if (isArray(cond.and)) {
      return map(cond.and, getIdConditionValue);
    } else if (isArray(cond.or)) {
      return map(cond.or, getIdConditionValue);
    }
    if (cond.id) return cond.id;
  }

const id = getIdConditionValue(condition).filter(x => x)[0];
```

It is working, but I would like to remove `.filter(x => x)[0]` part from the calling function, which I added because the returned value would be like this `[1, undefined]`.

Comment: It's a little hard to review code when there is missing code. If you could either, add some details about missing functions, or include the source That will help you get a good review.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Going along with what Blindman67 stated: Besides the obvious (i.e. getting a property value) What task does this code accomplish (the big picture)? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._".

Comment: Thanks for your kind words, I've edited the question as requested

Comment: Why is recursion required?

Comment: Are the two examples the only possible data structures?

Comment: You still have not provided the information on the two missing functions `map` and `isArray`. Their behaviour can not be assume and on the face of it your function has many sources of failure, that these functions may or may not protect you from.

Comment: @Blindman67 they are lodash's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the `map()` function used at the question having the same signature as `jQuery.map()` function used at the question, in order to avoid chaining `.filter()` to get the value at index `0` of the returned, you can use destructuring to assign `id` to the value at index `0` of the array returned from the function.

```js
function getIdConditionValue(cond) {
  if (Array.isArray(cond.and)) {
    return $.map(cond.and, getIdConditionValue);
  } else if (Array.isArray(cond.or)) {
    return $.map(cond.or, getIdConditionValue);
  }
  if (cond.id) return cond.id;
}

var condition = {
  or: [{
    and: [{
      id: 3
    }, {
      pageId: '1'
    }]
  }, {
    age: 10
  }]
}


const [id] = getIdConditionValue(condition);

console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

For Loash and Underscore signatures of `map()` signature (each library's `_.map()` returns an array having two elements, the fist is the expected result, the second `undefined`)  you can use

```
const [[id]] = getIdConditionValue(condition);
```

---

For an alternative recursive solution you can create a function that accepts an object and a property name for parameter, utilizes the recursive `replacer` function of `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`. If the property name is found during recursive iteration of property names of the object passed, a parameter of an immediately invoked arrow function declared as `undefined` is set to the property value, else `undefined` is returned from the function.

```js
const condition1 = {and: [{id:3}, {pageId:'1'}]};
const condition2 = {or: [{and: [{id: 3}, {pageId: '1'}]}, {age: 10 }]};
const condition3 = {and:[,,]};
const condition4 = {and:{or:[]}};
const condition5 = {or:[{or:[{id:1}]}]};

const getObjectPropertyValue = (o, prop) => (result =>
  (JSON[typeof o === 'string' ? 'parse' : 'stringify'](o, (key, value) => 
    key == prop ? (result = value) : value), result))(void 0);

let prop = 'id';

const id1 = getObjectPropertyValue(condition1, prop);

console.log(id1);

let condition2json = JSON.stringify(condition2);

const id2 = getObjectPropertyValue(condition2json, prop);

console.log(id2);

const id3 = getObjectPropertyValue(condition3, prop);

console.log(id3); // `undefined`

const id4 = getObjectPropertyValue(condition4, prop);

console.log(id4); // `undefined`

const id5 = getObjectPropertyValue(condition5, prop);

console.log(id5);
```

Comment: You have a typo in the second call, think you mean `condition2`, also your function is prone to throwing errors.  `{and:[,,]}`, `{and:{or:[]}}`, and `{or:[{or:[{id:1}]}]}` each throw a different error, and `{and:[{id:false}],id:null}` incorrectly returns `false`

Comment: @Blindman67 See updated post.

Comment: @Blindman67 What is the expected result of `{and:[{id:false}],id:null}`? The language at the question is _"the `id` property value"_.

Comment: I am guessing its `undefined` due to the line `if (cond.id) return cond.id;` from OP code However its is completely unclear what the actual needs are as the OP's code only prioritises `and` above `or` and gives no indication that `and` and `or` are defining logic. Eg `and` means all ids in array are truthy and `or` means any id is truthy. Unless the call to `map` has something going on in it (don't think so). At face values its a search for the FIRST truthy `id` along prop paths with `and` having priority, then `or` and last `id`.

Comment: @Blindman67 If you are referring to the `undefined` returned from the function at the answer, that is a decision made, here. The structure of the JavaScript plain object passed to the function at the answer is irrelevant to getting a specific property value. The name of the property itself, `"id"`, strongly implies that each distinct object or each element of an array of objects have precisely 1 property named `"id"`. The example objects at the question demonstrate that. As for further information from OP, that too, is not necessary for this answer to stand on its own re the current question.

Comment: @Blindman67 Updated the answer to throw an `Error` if the property is not found.

Comment: In JS I avoid throwing unless closure and dependent state will be damaged as to not allow the function to run again, also throwing is passing the buck to someone else.. If data is undefined then all you can return is undefined. The question is too ambiguous for a clear review on the functions logic

Comment: @Blindman67 The question is not ambiguous from perspective here. A plain JavaScript object cannot have duplicate property names. Reverted to returning `undefined` if the property name is not found in the object. Will update the answer to include a solution using the code at the question.

Comment: @Blindman67 See updated post.

Comment: @guest271314 Can you please explain the second syntax 
`const getObjectPropertyValue = (o, prop) => (result =>
  (JSON[typeof o === 'string' ? 'parse' : 'stringify'](o, (key, value) => 
    key == prop ? (result = value) : value), result))(void 0);`

Comment: @MustafaMagdy `(result => (JSON[typeof o === 'string' ? 'parse' : 'stringify'](o, (key, value) => key == prop ? (result = value) : value), result))(void 0)` is an immediately invoked arrow function. The purpose is to 1) define the variable `result` as `undefined` within the function without declaring the variable as a parameter of `getObjectPropertyValue` 2) return `result` either being set to `value` if `key == prop` or remain `undefined`. The call to `JSON[stringify/parse]` is wrapped in parenthesis to allow the comma operator which follows `((..), result)` where `result` is always returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the first result of any 'id' property in the structure you can just do a recursive search:

```js
let condition = {or: [{ and: [ { id: 3 }, { pageId: '1' } ] }, {age: 10}]}

function getFirstId(struct){
  for(let prop in struct){
    let val = struct[prop];
    if(prop === 'id') return val;
    if("object" === typeof val) return getFirstId(val);
  }
}

console.log(getFirstId(condition));
```

Comment: Your function is not safe when object or arrays contain cyclic references (throws error), returns the wrong value for `{id:false}`, unsafely uses `for in` and will recurse on a null property (eg `typeof null === "object"` is true)

Comment: true. other answers made assumptions about the structure of the input so I did as well. maybe I'll update it later.